# Drawing object to canvas (using Processing library, in Eclipse), returns an unexpected error

Tags: java, processing

I am using the library Processing in the Eclipse IDE, and I want to draw the 'Player' object 'p' to the screen using the p.show() method. All of the other Processing functions work, however when the this.show() function is ran it returns the error shown below. How can this be fixed?!

This program:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Game extends PApplet {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PApplet.main("Game");
    }

    public Player p = new Player();
    public static int cW = 1000, cH = 600;
    public void settings(){
        size(cW,cH);

    }

    public void setup(){
        background(51);

    }

    public void draw(){
        p.show();
    }


}
//PLAYER.JAVA CLASS
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Player extends PApplet{
    public int x,y,pSize = 30;
    public Player(){
        this.x = Game.cW/2;
        this.y = Game.cH/2; 

        }

    public void show(){
        noStroke();
        rect(this.x,this.y,this.pSize,this.pSize);
    }   

    }
```

Returns the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at processing.core.PApplet.noStroke(PApplet.java:13982)
  at Player.show(Player.java:12)
  at Game.draw(Game.java:21)
  at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2418)
  at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1540)
  at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have two different classes that both extend `PApplet`. Think of each extension of `PApplet` as a separate sketch. So you really only want one class that extends `PApplet`. To access Processing's functions in other classes, you'd have to pass in a reference to your main sketch. It would look like this:

```
public class Player{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int pSize = 30;

    public Player(int x, int y, PApplet sketch){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sketch = sketch; 
    }

    public void show(){
        sketch.noStroke();
        sketch.rect(x, y, pSize, pSize);
    }   
}
```

Then in your main sketch class, you'd use the `this` keyword to pass in a self-reference to the `Player` class:

```
public class Game extends PApplet {

    private Player p;

    private int cW = 1000;
    private int cH = 600;

    public void settings(){
        size(cW,cH);
        p = new Player(cW/2, cH/2, this);
    }

    //rest of your code
```